# R markdown multiple plots side-by-side with differnt width (out.width=??) knit to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I added these 2 (ggplot) plots side-by-side using Rmarkdwon, but as I did not want to duplicate the axis labels, the right bar chart area became wider than the left one. Any idea how I can adjust the width manually without changing their height (knit to pdf, see example below)?

````
```{r, F-ES3-reg-SS, fig.cap ="2 figures.",  fig.subcap = c("F.a", "F. b"), out.width = '50%', 
message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}
F_reg_ES3_PS
F_reg_ES3_RS
```
````

[image]

I was playing around a bit with `out.width = c('60%','40%')` and `out.height = c('30%','60%')`, but could not figure out anything convenient. I may manually adjust the width, but it would automatically change the height. Playing with out.height on top of it again affects the width and I could not figure out a convenient way to have the 2 bar charts of the same height and of approximately same width of the bar chart area.

Comment: Have you tried using fig.width & fig.height instead of out.width and out.height in your chunk options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to arrange the plots with `grid.arrange()`. You loose some automated forming (font size of captions, axis.text, legend etc.) and need to specify all manually within ggplot commands in order to obtain a nice layout. `fig.width` & `fig.height` may also do it, but again you need to layout the plot manually.